# filter by relationship sqlalchemy Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

There are two tables `Group` and `User`. `users` can belong to several groups at the same time.

**Group**

```
class Group(db.Model):
       """ Group model """
       __tablename__ = "group"
       id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
       project_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("project.id"), nullable=True)
       project = db.relationship("Project", foreign_keys=[project_id])
       active = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=True, index=True)
       name = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True)
```

**User**

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    """ User model """
    __tablename__ = "user"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)   
    email = db.Column(db.String(128), unique=True, index=True)
    email_confirmed = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)    
    password = db.Column(db.String(256), nullable=True)
    groups = db.relationship("Group", secondary=user_has_group, lazy="dynamic",
                     backref=db.backref("users", lazy="dynamic"))
```

There is a **code** that must display for each group of users.

```
groups = Group.query.all()
for group in groups:
    users = User.query.filter(group in User.groups).all()
```

**But the code is not running.**

Please help me how to get `users` to each `group`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `User` has a [back reference](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/backref.html) `backref=db.backref("users", lazy="dynamic")`

So from a `Group` object, you can use `group.users` to get the users in a given group, e.g.

```
groups = Group.query.all()
for group in groups:
    users = group.users
```